How manage columns with (values ; separated) by taking the columns name from values in R
I have a trick problem that i am not able to solve easily in R.
I have this data frame that comes from gtf genome hg19.

The code of the dataframe
data <- data.frame(
    chr.hg19v105 = c("chr9", "chr9", "chr9"),
    start.hg19v105 = c(133589268, 133710641, 133710834),
    end.hg19v105 = c(133763062, 133710833, 133710912),
    region.hg = c(
        "gene_id ABL1; transcript_id NM_007313.2; gene_name ABL1;",
        "gene_id ABL1; transcript_id NM_005157.6; exon_number 1; exon_id NM_005157.6.1; gene_name ABL1;",
        "gene_id ABL1; transcript_id NM_005157.6; exon_number 1; exon_id NM_005157.6.1; gene_name ABL1;"
    )
)

I would like to separate the region column taking the
gene_name id - transcipt_id - eson_number ecc as columns.
WARNING not all rows have the same elements.

In addition, I would like to remove the version from the transcript_id column.

It is easy to import it with the dedicated package obtaining the perfect columns separation.
gtf <- rtracklayer::import('./hg19.gtf')

gtf_df=as.data.frame(gtf)

But what I need it is to have the region column as a matching column with the other columns separated.
I have tried with the following code:
library(dplyr) 

library(tidyr)

df_separeted <- df %>% separate(region, into = c("V9","V10","V11","V12","V13","V14","V15","V16","V17","V18","V19","V20","V21","V22","V23","V24","V25","V26", "V30"), sep = ";")

But I am not able to manage the different position of the fields as well as the name columns.
It seems like a simple problem, but I am not able to figure out how to solve it.

Something like this:
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  chr.hg19v105 = c("chr9", "chr9", "chr9"),
  start.hg19v105 = c(133589268, 133710641, 133710834),
  end.hg19v105 = c(133763062, 133710833, 133710912),
  region.hg = c(
    "gene_id ABL1; transcript_id NM_007313.2; gene_name ABL1;",
    "gene_id ABL1; transcript_id NM_005157.6; exon_number 1; exon_id NM_005157.6.1; gene_name ABL1;",
    "gene_id ABL1; transcript_id NM_005157.6; exon_number 1; exon_id NM_005157.6.1; gene_name ABL1;"
  )
)

data_new = data %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(region.hg, delim = "; ") %>% 
  mutate(region.hg = str_remove(region.hg, ";$")) %>% 
  filter(region.hg != "") %>% 
  separate(region.hg, c("name", "value"), sep = " ") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  separate(transcript_id, c("transcript_id", "version"), sep = "\\.")

knitr::kable(data_new)




chr.hg19v105
start.hg19v105
end.hg19v105
gene_id
transcript_id
version
gene_name
exon_number
exon_id




chr9
133589268
133763062
ABL1
NM_007313
2
ABL1
NA
NA


chr9
133710641
133710833
ABL1
NM_005157
6
ABL1
1
NM_005157.6.1


chr9
133710834
133710912
ABL1
NM_005157
6
ABL1
1
NM_005157.6.1



Created on 2024-12-20 with reprex v2.0.2

Thank you a lot to trying to help me.
i got this error:
Error in values[spec$.name]:
! Can't subset columns with spec$.name.
✖ Subscript spec$.name can't contain the empty string.
✖ It has an empty string at location 3.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

Warning messages:
1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 35389 rows [3, 26, 44, 52, 55, 98, 101, 119,
122, 135, 138, ...].
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with NA in 313 rows [4792, 19680, 31095, ...].
3: Values from value are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use values_fn = list to suppress this warning.
• Use values_fn = {summary_fun} to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.
{data} |>
dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n(), .by = c(chr.hg, start, end, name)) |>
dplyr::filter(n > 1L)

Then there is something different in other rows of your data. Run the pipe step by step and check the output on each step. What step gives you the error?

I gave you an idea how to solve your problem. You should try to understand what the code is doing at each step and adjust to your data.

You could make a fields data frame first, then merge it to data frames from region.hg. The latter can be obtained using gsub for cleaning from version numbers (can be adapted if you only want clean transcript_id) then  strsplit, rbind, make 1st column to rownames, transpose, coerce as.data.frame. cbind this to data w/o the region.hg column.
> fields <- gregexpr("\\b[a-zA-Z_]+(?=\\s)", data$region.hg, perl=TRUE) |> 
+   regmatches(x=data$region.hg) |> unlist() |> unique()
> fields_df <- as.data.frame(array(,c(0, length(fields)), list(NULL, fields)))
> 
> data[1:3] |> 
+   cbind(
+     data$region.hg |> 
+       strsplit('; ') |> 
+       lapply(gsub, pat='\\..*|;', rep='') |> 
+       lapply(strsplit, ' ') |> 
+       lapply(do.call, what='rbind') |> 
+       lapply(\(x) as.data.frame(t(`rownames<-`(x[, -1, drop=FALSE], x[, 1])))) |> 
+       lapply(merge, fields_df, all=TRUE) |> 
+       do.call(what='rbind')
+   )
  chr.hg19v105 start.hg19v105 end.hg19v105 gene_id transcript_id gene_name exon_number   exon_id
1         chr9      133589268    133763062    ABL1     NM_007313      ABL1        <NA>      <NA>
2         chr9      133710641    133710833    ABL1     NM_005157      ABL1           1 NM_005157
3         chr9      133710834    133710912    ABL1     NM_005157      ABL1           1 NM_005157

